# Is it valid to pass use nullptr as a streambuf, to default initialize std::istream?

Tags: c++

Is this code standard-compliant?

```
class MyIstream : std::istream {
    MyStreamBuf buf;
public:
    MyIstream():
        std::istream(nullptr)
    {
        set_rdbuf(&buf);
    }
}
```

Do I have to create MyDummyStreamBuf, to bypass lack of default istream c-tor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/rdbuf

says

> 1. Returns the associated stream buffer. If there is no associated stream buffer, returns a null pointer.

Seems to me like it *is* valid to have an istream (basic_istream/basic_ios) with no stream associated, iow with nullptr.

BTW, I would perhaps use `rdbuf(...)`, instead of `set_rdbuf()`.
Interestingly, `rdbuf(ptr)` also seems to explicitly allow passing a nullptr:

> 2. Sets the associated stream buffer to sb. The error state is cleared by calling clear(). Returns the associated stream buffer before the operation. If there is no associated stream buffer, returns a null pointer.

Comment: Seems like you're right. Standard also handles case when sb is `nullptr`
https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.ios.cons#4